# install pip3 for conda

Tags: python, conda

Python2.6 was installed by default in my old centos server. Now I want to create a Python3 environment to install python3 specific module by conda

```
conda create -n py3 python=3.5.3
source activate py3
```

After activate the py3, I try to install hovercraft by `pip3 install hovercraft`, the shell tells "command not found: pip3".  At first I thought pip3 was installed with Python3, but the result was not the case.
So I think I can install it manually. The package gzip file was downloaded from [python package index](https://pypi.python.org/packages/18/ce/a39cdc0c467098a1c274b6cd3a62115f831340e45731d64bc7cc08fcdfc6/hovercraft-2.3.tar.gz), and install by `conda install --file hovercraft-2.3.tar.gz`. But it doesn't work.
Now I have two problems:

1. how to install pip3 for virtual-env create by conda?
2. Is it possible to install python package index downloaded package locally in conda?

Comment: Does just plain `pip` work after activating the virtualenv?

Comment: Hi, @wmorrell, plain pip is ok. `pip --version` show "pip 9.0.1 from /export/home/user01/envs/py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)". The message indicate this pip is pip3 for python3.5?

Comment: Yep, the virtualenv will add items to your shell `PATH` where both `python` and `pip` point to the correct 3.5.3 versions, and `pip` will install to your `py3` environment as long as it is active.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

pip3 and pip would make a difference only when you are not using any environment managers like virualenv (or) conda. Now as you are creating a conda environment which has python==3.x, pip would be equivalent to pip3.

Comment: this isn't true in some cases. For some libraries (like malmo https://github.com/Microsoft/malmo) the wheel requires a pip3 command

Comment: When a Conda env is created it's pip version looks as: `pip                conda-forge/noarch::pip-20.0.2-py_2` is this pip3?